# Trying to add form data into MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I currently have an HTML form with various feilds one for example is :

```
Please Enter First Name: <input type ="text" name="First_Name" /> <br />
```

I am trying to get the information from this form into my database. But it does not seem input anything into the database. Code is as follows.

```
<?php

$dbname='ecig';
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbpass='password';
$dbuser='eciguser';


$dbhandle = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("ecig",$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select examples");



$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES('$_POST[First_Name]', yes)");
mysql_close();

if (array_key_exists ('check_submit', $_POST )) 

echo "Your Name is : {$_POST['First_Name']}<br />";
echo "Your Second Name is : {$_POST['Second_Name']}<br />";
echo "Your Email Address is : {$_POST['Email_Address']}<br />";
echo "Your Password Is : {$_POST['Password']}<br />";

?>
```

The question is as this is having no impact on my database, is there something i am missing and need to add to my SQL code so that the php and the SQL interact with each other and input the data?

Or am i missing something from the INSERT INTO statement?

Anyway help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Nice [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your query, 'yes'  at the end must have quotes.

Try running your query first directly against MySQL to determine if your syntax is correctly, then just replace the values you want.

Should look like this for your example:

```
$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]', 'yes')");
```

A bit of advice,  sanitize your input if you are receiving data from the user, or you will be vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

And use mysqli_ functions since mysql_ functions are officially deprecated by now.  You can read more about those in almost any site, like w3schools.com

Full example of insert with mysqli_ : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Good luck

Comment: awesome thanks seemed to work, Yes someone said something very similar about mysqli, so i'll take a look at that thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, mysqli is pretty straight forward and the functions look a lot like mysql_ . Plus, if you learn about mysqli's prepared statements you don't need to worry about sanitizing your user input.
Please don't forget to select the answer if it worked for you =) cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

```
$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['First_Name'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[Second_Name])."')");
```